# a simple way to produces classes with global state

Tags: python, class, oop

Suppose I have a class, defined, for example, thus:

```
class testclass():
    cl = []

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.cl.append(x)
```

Now, I want to create a class which is identical to testclass **except** I don't want testclass' state `cl`, but rather its own individual state.

Experiment shows that inheriting from `testclass` inherits `cl`, so that does not work. Any words of wisdom appreciated. Does this require the whole metaclass machinery? (which I don't quite understand enough yet)

Comment: Have you tried inheriting `testclass` and overwrite the `cl` class attribute in the definition of the inherited class (e.g. `class Foo(testclass): cl=[]`? If this doesn't work for whatever reason, can you describe why it doesn't work? (Which does suggest you probably need metaclasses in that case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A metaclass isn't so hard here if you just think of it as a subclass of the class type. You can give it an `__init__()` that sets the `cl` list just like you would for an instance and each class get's its own class property:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __init__(cls, *args):
        cls.cl = []
    
class testclass(metaclass=Meta):        
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.cl.append(n)

class t_child(testclass):
    pass

t = testclass(10)
print(t.cl)
# [10]

t2 = testclass(20)
print(t2.cl)
# [10, 20]

t3 = t_child(100)
print(t3.cl)
# [100]

t4 = t_child(100)
print(t4.cl)
# [100, 100]

t5 = testclass(30)
print(t5.cl)
# [10, 20, 30]
```

Comment: Truly you are wise in the ways of science!